# Matching delayed signals

Tags: correlation

I have pairs of 1d digitised waveform signals which are almost identical - except there are sections which are the same in both but one is delayed slightly.
I need to find sections and the delay with the corresponding section in the other channel.

I can set a maximum delay BUT I need to measure a delay to less than the sample interval - so some sort of convolution/correlation approach rather than a simple feature id.

Any suggestions where to start?

Comment: Hey Martin can you post some plots for us to see?

Comment: @Mohammad - now I have some sample data it's worse than I thought - it's so noisy and with large scale DC variation I will need to do a lot of scaling before they are even viewable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a good candidate for a two step approach:

Step 1 would be a pretty coarse running cross correlation with a threshold detector to identify what parts in the signals are matching.

Step 2 would than determined the actual delay. There are various ways to get sub sample resolution:

1. Upsample to desired resolution and then cross correlate
2. Short term fourier transform and match a linear phase difference with a weighted least squares approach
3. Delayed lock loop with a fractional delay filter
4. Match the the two signals in with an adaptive filter. Then calculate the fourier transform of the filter impulse response and calculate the delay through a linear phase match

Comment: Thanks - it's actually harder than I implied, the main signal is identical (except for noise) in each channel - it's only parts that are delayed. Although your approach is still a good one